# How to get customer custom dropdown value with text in magento2?

Tags: magento2, attributes, customer, customer-attribute

I have created customer custom attribute *'**segments**'* with the below options:

**Options: SME, Reseller, Others**

I want get `segments` value with text based on the `customer id` in magento2.

How to achieve this.

Thanks in Advance :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can get value and text by using this code:

```
<?php

$customerId = 12;
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$customer = $objectManager->create('Magento\Customer\Model\Customer')->load($customerId);

//Get segments value
$segmentsValue = $customer->getCustomAttributeText('segments')->getValue();

//Get segments text
$segmentsText = $customer->getResource()
->getAttribute('segments')
    ->getSource()
        ->getOptionText($customer->getData('segments'));

echo $segmentsText;
```

Comment: Is this a Magento 2 solution? I got Call to undefined method Magento\Customer\Model\Data\Customer::getCustomAttributeText()

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

protected $_customerSession;

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession
) {
    $this->_customerSession = $customerSession;
}

public function getMyAttibuteValue() {
    $optionId = $this->_customerSession->getCustomer()->getSegments();
    $attribute = $this->_customerSession->getCustomer()->getResource()->getAttribute('segments');
    if ($attribute->usesSource()) {
        $myAttributeValue = $attribute->getSource()->getOptionText($optionId);
    }
}
```